# How to capture iOS on-screen keyboard key press and key release events

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

Apple has recently provided a way to handle keydown and keyup events from keys typed on an external keyboard; see [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-detect-keyboard-input-using-pressesbegan-and-pressesended). In this new API, one must override pressesBegan and pressesEnded functions, which provide event-related information, including the key pressed (or released) by the user.

I was wondering if there is anything similar to this when using the on-screen keyboards. I tried to implement these functions, but they will only be triggered when the device is hooked up to an external keyboard. Nothing happens when using on-screen keyboards though.

Have you guys heard of any alternative?

Thanks.

Comment: They are not keys so there isn't any such thing.

Comment: Whats wrong about `UIControl.Event.editingChanged`?

Comment: @matt Not sure what you mean about them not being keys. Do you mean that they are not physical keys, therefore they shouldn't trigger an event?

Comment: @LeoDabus I am not familiar with '''UIControl.Event.editingChanged''', but I assume I'd be able to listen to changes that happen on a text field? I need the precise keystroke's timestamp along with other information (whether the key was pressed / released, the force with which the key was pressed, which key was pressed). I'd be able to retrieve all that with pressesBegan/pressesEnded.

Comment: I don't get whats the purpose of monitoring a key instead of the textfield content. Note that the textfield only changes when the key is released and this is intentional. You always have the chance to move your finger from one key to another  before releasing it which is not possible with a physical keyboard..

Comment: @LeoDabus I need this information (press/release, force, key pressed) for research purposes. I wish I could only focus on content, but I need a bit more. Thanks for your help, though!

Comment: All you can do is override touches began / ended

Comment: @LeoDabus I tried that too, but these functions will not be called either. Only UI elements part of my view can trigger touchesBegan/touchesEnded events. Maybe I am missing something important; I am still a beginner in Swift.

Comment: @DennisCunha You would probably have to implement your own keyboard

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiinputviewcontroller

Comment: Yeah, that's what I started doing yesterday. Thanks for your time, @LeoDabus. I appreciate your help!